# Display a $scope variable using another $scope variable

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

### Display a scope variable which is similar to ng-repeat element in Angularjs

These are my scope variables

```
$scope.published = true;
$scope.count = 3;
```

I also have an array called labels

```
$scope.labels = ['published', 'count'];
```

In the view I want to view these data as the label name - label value.

```
<div ng-repeat="label in labels">
    {{label}} -  {{Here I want the value from the Scope variable}}
</div>
```

Can someone help me how to access the scope variable in this kind of scenario?

Comment: Assuming your HTML is within context of an `ng-controller`, which is assigned to the same controller containing your `$scope` variables, it should just be a matter of using `{{count}}` or `{{published}}` in your HTML if you want to display the values literally. If you've aliased your controller (e.g. `ng-controller="Ctrl as foo"`) then you'll need to prefix the interpolations with the alias (e.g. `{{foo.count}}`).

Comment: Thanks But I want to display the value dynamically, because there are around 20 values which I need to iterate through ng-repeat, So just using {{count}} or {{published}} won't work in my use case.

Comment: Oops, I misread your question. Right, in that case, either map the assign the `labels` collection to objects which index the `$scope` properties, or have a function which returns the latter and make use of it with your `ng-repeat` (e.g. `ng-repeat="obj in getObjs()"`). If the `labels` collection ever varies, then the latter approach ensures you don't need to explicitly remap the labels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `this` identifier and [bracket notation property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation):

```
<div ng-repeat="label in labels">
    {{label}} -  {{this[label]}}
</div>
```

From the Docs:

> It is possible to access the context object using the identifier `this` and the locals object using the identifier `$locals`.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Expression Context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation)

### The DEMO

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.published = true;
    $scope.count = 3;
    $scope.labels = ['published', 'count'];
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="label in labels">
        {{label}} -  {{this[label]}}
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Map your labels to `{key:"labelKey", value:"valueInScope"}` so you can use them in the template.

Something like this could work

```
labels = ['published','count']
         .map(
             function(label){
                return {key:label,value:$scope[label]}
             });
```

then use

```
<div ng-repeat="label in labels">
   {{label.key}} - {{label.value}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think this is also correct but it needs an extra map function